# Is netty receive events concurrency ? How about DownStream and Upsream events?

Tags: java, events, concurrency, netty

events docs
http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelEvent.html

For example:
Can get two events at the same time?

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

if messageReceived take long time, can i receive another messageReceived in another thread?
Or netty have queue of all events ?

another example

```
int i=0;

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    i++;
}
```

is increment correct?

Another question.

Is upstream events and downstream events working concurrently ?

Answer (score 4):

Thats not complete right..

If you use a new handler instance for every channel you don't need to make them thread-safe. The only exception is when you implement a DownstreamHandler, as downstream events can be fired by any thread.

So as long as you only care about ChannelUpstreamHandler you don't need todo any synchronization (if you use one handler per channel)

Comment: Maybe you can clarify that for me: If a thread outside of the IO Workers calls write() it will travel down the ChannelPipeline. So far so good but: In which thread will the downstream Events beeing executed? Does netty pick an IO Worker for that? If yes: Why does it not use the same mechanic as upstream events (one Thread per Channel). If not: Isn't that a bad idea in case I don't want non IO Threads to proably wait for a lock to accquire while another upstream event is in execution? (I think of potentionally longer running stuff like encryption handshake)

Answer (score 1):

found in javadoc

Thread safety

handleUpstream will be invoked sequentially by the same thread (i.e. an I/O thread) and therefore a handler does not need to worry about being invoked with a new upstream event before the previous upstream event is finished.

Thread safety

handleDownstream may be invoked by more than one thread simultaneously. If the handler accesses a shared resource or stores stateful information, you might need proper synchronization in the handler implementation.

messageReceived is Upstream event, and will be invoked sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the netty framework keeps a pool of threads. It will call as many 'messageRecieved' methods concurrently as it has threads. Each method that you execute needs to be thread safe.

Comment: Or you can just add a new instance of the handler per channel if you not need to share content. An other option is to use ChannelLocal for sharing state informations. Checkout the javadocs:http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelLocal.html